# How to use loop in php http library Guzzle

Tags: php, arrays, guzzle

I have an array that post to an api via Guzzle which is stored in `$_SESSION['hi2']`

`[{"receiverID":"7","countryCode":"852","phone":"96853214","message":"msg"},{"receiverID":"19","countryCode":"852","phone":"98745123","message":"msg2"}]`

Below is the PHP code that post the array to the api

***guzzle.php***

```
<?php 
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$client = new Client([
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json',

     ]
]);

$response = $client->post('http://mmm.clinictech.com.hk:91/SMS',
    ['body' => $_SESSION['hi2']]
);

echo  var_export($response->getStatusCode(), true);
echo  var_export($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);?>
```

I have a html page with a button that once clicked will be direct to the guzzle.php that post the api

```
 <a href="guzzle.php"><button name="send">send</button></a>
```

The issue that i am facing is that the API only accept a single object each time

ie

> {"receiverID":"teststring","countryCode":"teststring2","phone":"teststring3","message":"teststring4"}

So if there's more than one object in the array, i have to use loop, i have tried to use foreach loop, but invain. 
Any idea?thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may to use `foreach` to get all results:

```
<?php 
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$client = new Client([
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json',

     ]
]);

$response = [];
foreach ($_SESSION['hi2'] as $query) {
    $response[] = $client->post('http://mmm.clinictech.com.hk:91/SMS',
        ['body' => $query]
    );
}
echo  var_export($response->getStatusCode(), true);
echo  var_export($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);?>
```

Comment: I cant send the sms via the api now, is it because  the the array key is missing?